# Getting the first created document and grouping by field name in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to get the very first department created for each company, however, I'm confused with the aggregate query.

**Documents:**

```
[
 {
  _id: "5b7579f2deea1c6e46fd9739",
  name: "Sales",
  companyId: "123",
 },
 {
   _id: "5c5779f1dffe1c6e45df3973",
   name: "Security",
   companyId: "123",
 },
 {
   _id: "5d9759f5ceda1c6e64df9772",
   name: "Human Resource",
   companyId: "789",
 },
]
```

I'm expecting a result like this:

**Expected Result:**

```
[
 {
  _id: "5b7579f2deea1c6e46fd9739",
  name: "Sales",
  companyId: "123",
 },
 {
   _id: "5d9759f5ceda1c6e64df9772",
   name: "Human Resource",
   companyId: "789",
 },
]
```

But I'm getting only one result with my query.

**Actual Result:**

```
[
 {
  _id: "5b7579f2deea1c6e46fd9739",
  name: "Sales",
  companyId: "123",
 },
]
```

**Aggregate Query:**

```
db.getCollection('departments').aggregate([
  {
    $sort:{ item: 1 }
  },
  {
    $group: {
        _id:'$item',
      companyId: { $first:'$companyId'},
      name: { $first:'$name'},
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Are your sample documents correct? First and second have the same _id value which is forbidden, also all of the documents have the same companyId.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I just invented the id since it's for sample here in SO only, I'll edit it thanks.

Comment: Even with this update, I don't see any logic for expected result, maybe you need to adjust companyId values, they all have same companyId.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://mongoplayground.net/p/dPNZhGnog1s  
It would be good an additional field to be able to sort on it like a date field.

Comment: That playground is so cool! Also your solution worked. I hope I can upvote you as best answer! Thanks so much.

Comment: I posted an answer with a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `companyId` field like this:

```js
db.departments.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$companyId",
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$doc"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c0ThAJfyMrr)

If you have a natural sort field like a date field, it would be good to apply sort stage on that field before the group stage.